# Directly adding API data into a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, hash

I'm using this GiantBomb API(https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb) to get a list of games. User search through games, and then add it to their library. Users can also view other people's libraries. I have it working, except that items I am adding to the library cannot recall all the API data. I want to put GiantBomb::Game data into a has so I can call data in the view like @game.description and whatnot.

Here is my Games Controller. There is a search function, a show page for individual games, and my library function which adds individual games to a user's library page.

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

#Users search for games
  def index
  @games = GiantBomb::Search.new().query(params[:query]).resources('game').limit(100).fetch
  end

#individual game profile page
  def show
  @game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(params[:id])
  end

#Adding games to user libraries
  def library
    type = params[:type]
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    if type == "add"
      current_user.library_additions << @game
      redirect_to user_library_path(current_user), notice: "Game was added to your library"

    elsif type == "remove"
      current_user.library_additions.delete(@game)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Game was removed from your library"
    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to game_path(@game), notice: "Looks like nothing happened. Try once more!"
    end
  end


private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name, :id)
  end
end
```

Games are added to the library view this code in the view.

```
 <% if user_added_to_library?(current_user, game) %>

            <%= link_to 'Remove from library', add_game_path(game['id'], type: "remove", game: game), method: :put %>

          <% else %>
            <%= link_to 'Add to library', add_game_path(game['id'], type: "add", game: game), method: :put %>
          <% end %>
```

On my show page I am pulling directly from the API via GiantBomb::Game.detail(params[:id]), so I can call parameters like below:

```
<div class="cards">

  <div class="card">
  <%= image_tag @game.image['medium_url'], class: "cover"%>
  <div class="container">
    <h2><%= @game.name %></h2>
    <p><%= @game.deck %></p>
    <p><%= @game.id %></p>
    <% if @game.platforms === nil %>
    <p>Platform Unknown</p>
    <% else %>
    <p><%= @game.platforms[0]['name'] %></p>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= @game.original_release_date.to_s[0..3] %></p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

However, I can't use @game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(params[:id]) for my library function, I have to use @game = Game.new(game_params). My game model only has name and id associated with it, so it seems I can only display that information on the library page.

Here is my library controller.

```
class LibraryController < ApplicationController
  #find user id through params
  def index
    @library_games = User.find(params[:id]).library_additions
  end
end
```

And it's index page:

```
<h1>Library</h1>

<% if @library_games.exists? %>
<% @library_games.each do |game| %>
    <div class="container">
      <p><%= game.name%></p>
      <p><%= game.id %></p>

    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% else %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="message-body">You haven't added any games to your library yet. <%= link_to 'Add some', root_path %>.</div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

If I use game.deck I get an undefined method, however if I use game['deck'] I don't get an error, but nothing displays unlike in my show page.

So do I need to add a migration for each individual piece of data (deck, image, platforms etc.) to my game model, or is there a way to edit my library method so that I can pass all the GiantBomb::Game data into my library_additions so I can just call any data via @game.insertdatahere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you noted, your Game model is storing only `name` and `id` because that's all that `game_params` contains, and possibly also the only columns you've defined on the underlying table. If you look at your database (`rails db`) and run `SELECT * FROM games;`, you can see the data that's actually being persisted into your database.

So, if you'd like to store the full set of data, the quickest answer is to just store it as an arbitrary hash. The `GiantBomb::Game` record does not come with an easy way to get a hash of the data within it, but you can use a little snippet of metaprogramming to pull everything in it out:

```
data = Hash[game.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], game.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]
```

Then, you can store the hash either in a new `TEXT` column and tell Rails to [serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) it, or if you're using a database with support for it, just directly into a `JSON`/`JSONB` column. Since I don't know your database, here's an example of the serialization approach:

```
# in a new migration
change_table :games do |t|
  t.text :data
end

# game.rb
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :data

  # this method will overwrite the `data` column with the latest game data from the
  # API. I've extracted it so refreshing the data if it becomes stale is easier.
  def fetch_data
    game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(id)
    self.data = Hash[game.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], game.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]
  end

  # ...
end

# in your controller
game = Game.new(game_params)
game.fetch_data

# in wherever you want to access the data
platforms = game.data["platforms"]
```

Now, I looked at the GiantBomb code a bit, and it instantiates its own records just from a plain hash (parsed from a JSON API call, I assume), so you could re-instantiate them from your stored data too:

```
giant_bomb_game = GiantBomb::Game.new(game.data)
```

This might help you address the concerns in your second-to-last paragraph: your views could all work off of instances of the GiantBomb::Game type, rather than having to deal with sometimes getting Game and sometimes getting GiantBomb::Game.

For example, if you added the above as a new method on Game:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
 
  def to_giant_bomb_game
    GiantBomb::Game.new(data)
  end
end
```

Then your view could use that method to succinctly rehydrate the objects into what you want:

```
<h1>Library</h1>

<% if @library_games.exists? %>
<% @library_games.map(&:to_giant_bomb_game).each do |game| %>
    <div class="container">
      <p><%= game.name%></p>
      <p><%= game.id %></p>
      <p><%= game.deck %></p>
//etc
```

I should probably stop here, but because we're in Ruby, it *is* possible (and easy) to go a step further and make Game act as if it's a GiantBomb::Game. If this is a production application you're being paid to develop, please turn back now, but otherwise:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  def method_missing(*args)
    if (gbgame = to_giant_bomb_game) && gbgame.respond_to?(args.first)
      return gbgame.public_send(*args)    
    end

    super(*args)
  end
end
```

This will make a `Game` instance that receives a method it doesn't know, like `deck`, call that method on the `GiantBomb::Game` instance it knows how to construct. So your `@game.deck` call will work the same no matter if `@game` is a Game or a GiantBomb::Game. Which is neat, but can also lead to some super confusing bugs down the road... such is the curse of metaprogramming.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I went ahead and ran the migration and added your suggestions to my code, yet I am getting an undefined method to_h however for the fetch_data method you described. If I remove the to_h and try to add a game, the to_giant_bomb_game method gives me a undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: @SJK sorry, `to_h` is a common convention but the GiantBomb gem doesn't implement it. You will have to implement it yourself -- something like `data = Hash[game.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], game.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]` can work, though it's ugly. I'll update my answer text with that.

Comment: Thank you for your update, I managed to get it working now. I really appreciate you taking the time to give such a detailed and thorough answer!